# R ggplot customizing fill colors and legend titles

Tags: r

I am trying to customize the legend in a bar plot. I have two parts I am trying to adjust, and am able to do so individually, but when I combine the two steps only one is kept.

For example, this `data`:

```
State           Num.Class   Num.Tweets
Pennsylvania    Cowboys     98
Pennsylvania    Patriots    10
Pennsylvania    Eagles      174
Pennsylvania    Steelers    70
Texas           Cowboys     233
Texas           Patriots    42
Texas           Eagles      30
Texas           Steelers    26
California      Cowboys     57
California      Patriots    32
California      Eagles      39
California      Steelers    20
Massachusetts   Cowboys     23
Massachusetts   Patriots    74
Massachusetts   Eagles      1
Massachusetts   Steelers    3
```

with this code:

```
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x=State, y = Num.Tweets, fill = Num.Class)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
g
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

I can (1) change the colors on their own:

```
g <- g + scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "darkgreen", "navyblue", "gold"))
g
```

[image]

and (2) the legend titles on their own:

```
g <-  g + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Team", labels = c("Cowboys", "Eagles", "Patriots", "Steelers") ) 
g
```

[image]

But if try (1) and (2) together the first setting is overwritten, but I'm unable to figure out how to combine these settings into one statement.

```
g <- g + scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "darkgreen", "navyblue", "gold")) +
      + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Team", labels = c("Cowboys", "Eagles", "Patriots", "Steelers") ) 
g
```

(Same as last image.)

How can that be done: keeping the fill colors and legend titles as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use two different types of `scale_fill` at the same time.
Keep only the manual one:

```r
g + scale_fill_manual(name = "Team", 
                      labels = c("Cowboys", "Eagles", "Patriots", "Steelers"), 
                      values = c("blue", "darkgreen", "navyblue", "gold"))
```

[image]

Comment: Huh, I thought I tried this but I guess not. Thanks.